# Android GLSL Optimizing

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

So far, my game has run smoothly on any device i've tried (phones, mostly), always 50-60fps.  i just tested a Nook HD+, and i'm getting 18fps - barely playable. after some digging, i narrowed it down to one shader:

```
    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "uniform lowp vec4 vColor;" +
        "uniform sampler2D mTexture;" +
        "uniform lowp vec4 mLightPos;" +
        "uniform lowp vec4 mCamPos;" +
        "varying lowp vec2 fragTexCoord;" +
        "varying lowp vec4 wNormal;" +
        "varying lowp vec4 wPos;" +
        "varying lowp vec2 bumpMapCoords;" +
        "void main() {" +
            "lowp vec4 bumpColor = texture2D(mTexture, bumpMapCoords);" +
            "lowp vec3 newNorm = -normalize((bumpColor.rgb - .5) * 2.0);\n" +
            "newNorm = normalize(vec3(newNorm.x, newNorm.y, newNorm.z));\n" +
            "lowp vec3 lightDir = normalize(mLightPos.xyz - wPos.xyz);" +
            "lowp vec3 viewDir = normalize(mCamPos.xyz - wPos.xyz);" +
            "lowp float d = dot(lightDir, normalize(newNorm.xyz));" + // clamp
            "lowp vec3 refl = normalize(reflect(-lightDir, newNorm.xyz));" + 
            "lowp float spec = clamp(pow(dot(refl, viewDir), 13.0), 0.0, 1.0);" +// clamp 
            "lowp float total = d + spec;" +
            //////note this line:
                ////"total = .5;" +

            "  gl_FragColor = total * vec4(vColor.r, vColor.g, vColor.b, .7);" +
        "}";
```

long story short, if i uncomment **total = .5f** i get a silky 57fps; without it, 18. so my first question is, is  there compiler optimization going on that says, "everything above **total = .5f** is unused, so don't do it. clearly, that would impact performance. however, if it doesn't optimize, then i'm at a loss. any ideas?

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of normalizations... I don't think I've ever seen anything quite like that. If your GPU is arithmetic limited, my money's on that causing your slowdown. You should be able to move a lot of those calculations into the vertex shader and use interpolation instead of normalizing a million times in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you uncomment `total = .5;`, the compiler gets rid of all unused variables. In this case, it will discard all the computation you do, simply because it doesn't affect the output of the shader. GPU compilers are very effective in removing anything that doesn't affect the output of a shader and it can be a bit confusing while debugging.

Apart from that, your shader is too complicated, it should look sth like this:

```
    void main() {
        lowp vec3 N = (texture2D(mTexture, bumpMapCoords).rgb - .5f) * -2.f;
        N = normalize(N);
        lowp vec3 L = normalize(mLightPos.xyz - wPos.xyz);
        lowp vec3 E = normalize(-wPos.xyz);
        lowp vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(L, N));

        lowp float d = max(dot(L, N), 1.f));
        lowp float spec = pow(max(dot(R,E), 1.f), 13.f);

        gl_FragColor = (d + spec) * vec4(vColor.rgb, .7f);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the info about compilers, didn't know if it was smart enough to remove unused variables or not. i'm off to optimize shader code.

Comment: also, fyi the f suffix and max() function are unsupported on several devices.

Comment: Might be, tbh I don't know OpenGL ES...  f suffix is a force of habit, but considering max, in this case, it's better to use than clamp (only one comparison) and afaik if clamp is defined, than max should be as well...